# Restrict access to a webform node to only a particular role in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Im using Drupal 6.19 and have used the webform module in Drupal to create a form on my Drupal site.The form shows up in the navigation menu.
Is it possible to restrict access to the form to only a particular role ?. 
That is, i want only users belonging to a particular role to be able to see the form link in the navigation menu and be able to access it.Users belonging to other roles should not see the form link in the navigation menu and also should not be able to access it.
Can this be done ?

Please help
Thank You

Answer (score 4):

as always, there are several ways to skin a cat... :)

how about using the [node privacy by role](http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole) module? seems to do exactly what you are asking for. you can set it by content type or on a per-node basis, if you need control that granular.

other modules to look at at: [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and [webform submission acl](http://drupal.org/project/webform_submissions_acl)

hope that helps.

Comment: +1'd for simple and direct. You want to restrict View access to the node. Any standard access control mechanism that does this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should check [hook_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_access/6) to do it manually. Or look at the [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module if it may help.